# WiX Installer dialog closing after custom action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a WiX installer that has a dialog with a button on it.

When I click the button, I want it to open a web page using the default browser.

I've managed to successfully do this, but the problem is that after I click on the button and the web page is launched, the installer closes.

What do I need to do to keep it open?

Here is my code (just the relevant parts):

```
<!-- the button -->
<Control Id="webpage" Type="PushButton" X="15" Y="245" Width="110" Height="17" Text="!(loc.webpage)" TabSkip="no" Default="yes" >

<!-- the button action -->
<Publish Dialog="MyDlg" Control="webpage" Event="DoAction" Value="OpenWebPage">1</Publish>

<!-- the action (is defined in a dll) -->
<Binary Id='FooBinary' SourceFile='Dll1.dll'/>
<CustomAction Id='OpenWebPage' BinaryKey='FooBinary' DllEntry='open_website' Execute='immediate' Return='check'/>
```

Comment: The action to open a web page would always happen when they click the close button. If you don't want it to close how would you propose that they close the installer? Seems like a UX issue. I would add a second button for closing the install or opening the web page.

Comment: I actually have 4 buttons: Next, Back, Cancel and OpenPage.
The installer is closed via the Cancel button (or the standard X button from any standard Windows window). I just want the OpenPage button to open a web page and leave the installer alone (i.e. don't close it). That's it!